# Counting of algebraic data types

Tags: haskell, theory, algebraic-data-types

I'm reading/listening to Chris Taylor's presentation on algebraic data types.

http://chris-taylor.github.io/blog/2013/02/10/the-algebra-of-algebraic-data-types/

And there's a section on function types. Specifically the example

```
data Bool = True | False
data Trio = First | Second | Third
```

Given the law

```
a -> b == B^A
```

Given

```
Trio -> Bool     should equal     8
```

**Why 8 and not 6 via multiplication?**

If I'm understanding this correctly, the concrete combinations should be

```
First  -> True
First  -> False
Second -> True
Second -> False
Third  -> True
Third  -> False
```

Isn't that just 6 concrete implementations of `Trio -> Bool`?

What am I missing?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Those aren't full implementations. For the full implementations, it is like counting from 0 to 7 (which is a total of 8 = 2<sup>3</sup> numbers) in binary, with each line of each implementation representing one of the three bits. All the possibilities look like this (if we call our function `f`):

1)

```
f First  = False
f Second = False
f Third  = False
```

2)

```
f First  = True
f Second = False
f Third  = False
```

3)

```
f First  = False
f Second = True
f Third  = False
```

4)

```
f First  = True
f Second = True
f Third  = False
```

5)

```
f First  = False
f Second = False
f Third  = True
```

6)

```
f First  = True
f Second = False
f Third  = True
```

7)

```
f First  = False
f Second = True
f Third  = True
```

8)

```
f First  = True
f Second = True
f Third  = True
```