# Why Algebraic Data Type such as function type an exponential?

Tags: haskell

Some Haskell reading material describes function type as an exponential.  That is 'a -> b' is analogous to b to the power of a.

I don't get how function type is exponential. Suppose we have Bool -> RBG where RBG only has three possible values. Then 3 to the power of 2 is 9.  If we are counting morphisms, then there are only six possible morphisms not nine. True -> R, True -> B, True -> G, False -> R, False -> B, False -> G. I don't get it.

This https://bartoszmilewski.com/2015/03/13/function-types/ post say:

Functions like isupper or isspace are implemented using tables, which are equivalent to tuples of 256 Boolean values. A tuple is a product type, so we are dealing with products of 256 Booleans: bool × bool × bool × ... × bool.

Assuming the function is char -> bool where char is 256 possible input and 2 possible output, we have 2 to the power of 256.  For each char, we can get either True or False.  Why do we need to take the product of all bools not the sum?

Answer (score 8):

What you seem to be missing here is that `True -> R` is not a function by itself, but half a function. The function also needs to return something for `False`. There are 3 different possible outcomes for `False`, and 3 different possible outcomes for `True`, leading to `3 ** 2` or 9 total functions. You can verify this for yourself:

```hs
False -> R, True -> R
False -> R, True -> G
False -> R, True -> B
False -> G, True -> R
False -> G, True -> G
False -> G, True -> B
False -> B, True -> R
False -> B, True -> G
False -> B, True -> B
```

In the case of `Char -> Bool` functions like `isspace`, there are 256 different characters, and each one has one of 2 possible outcomes, leading to `2 * 2 * 2 * ... * 2` or `2 ** 256` total tables. You can manually verify this on a smaller case.

Comment: I see. I should think in term of functions that generate unique combination of input and output instead of unique mapping from Bool to RBG.  Example given:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23922807/counting-of-algebraic-data-types

Comment: @Steve-Liang: Right, the *values* of type `Bool -> RGB` are the functions themselves, `\ case { False -> R; True -> R }`, `\ case { False -> R; True -> G }`, and so on; not just the individual case branches `False -> R`, `False -> G`, &c.

Answer (score 3):

> there are only six possible morphisms not nine. True -> R, True -> B, True -> G, False -> R, False -> B, False -> G

You haven't described any single function from Bool to RGB here. You've listed the cartesian product of Bool and RGB, confirming that indeed a tuple is a product type. There are 6 pairs, but 9 functions.

Let's write a function `f :: Bool -> RGB`. First, we will have to choose a value for `f False`. There are three choices. Now, for each of these possibilities, we need to choose a value for `f True`. Again, there are three choices. So, we chose one of three things, and then for each such choice we needed to make another choice of 3 things. That's a total of 3*3 = 3<sup>2</sup> possible functions of this type.